# How do you find the EBDA address?

Tags: ibm-pc, x86

Normally, the "Extended BIOS Data Area" (EBDA) is located at the segment stored at `0x0040:0x000E`, but this is only true for EISA and MCA systems (at least that's what I found in various specs). This [BDA Map](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html) says that on older systems, the word at `0x040E` is "LPT 4 port address", while on PS/2 systems it is indeed the EBDA segment.

How can you find out the location of the EBDA in older systems, and how can you find out that `0x040E` points to it and is not describing something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Older systems don’t have an extended BIOS data area, so there’s nothing to find.

Systems with an EBDA place it at the top of conventional memory, *i.e.* usually as the last 1024 bytes (or in some cases, 2048 or 4096 bytes) before the 640K boundary. This can be used to check whether the value at 0040Eh points to the EBDA: you can compare it with the installed conventional memory size given by [interrupt 12h](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/bios/12.html#633) or the word at 00413h; if it exists, the EBDA comes just after the end of conventional memory as indicated by that word.

A less reliable test is to check the number of installed parallel ports ([interrupt 11h](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/bios/11.html#610), or the byte at 00411h); if 0040Eh is non-zero and one or two parallel ports are installed, 0040Eh points to the EBDA.

*The Undocumented PC* only mentions the former test, and the Linux kernel’s EBDA detection also only relies on checking the given address against known memory boundaries.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because there are systems with less than 640K of conventional memory (e.g. 512K), and I didn't think the EBDA could be found right after the conventional memory unless there is the full 640K (if there was less, there would be a gap). Also, I'm not sure if `INT 0x11` can help, because the number of ports it can return seems to be between 0 and 3 (so it can't say anything about the 4th port).

Comment: The EBDA is in memory, so systems with only 512K with an EBDA (which would be surprising, but let’s imagine) would have the EBDA at the top of the 512K. The equipment byte indicates either 0 or 3 on systems with four parallel ports, so three is indeed inconclusive (I suspect however that systems with four BIOS-managed parallel ports don’t have an EBDA).

Comment: I suppose that if the value at `0x040E` is above `0x8000` or so, there isn't any real chance for it to be the address of a parallel port, right?

Comment: Right, I think it would be safe to conclude that.

Comment: Some BIOSes have an option to choose whether EBDA is located at last 1k which does reduce available conventional memory amount by 1k, or located at 0:300h (or 30h:0 which is the same address).

Comment: @Justme The assignable memory is not for a full standard EBDA, but just for the 2*16 bytes required for the disk parameter table if Type 47 is selected in SETUP. This option started to disappear when BIOS shadowing was no longer optional, because in that case, the hard disk parameters are stored in the shadow ROM.